# Why didn't the gun turrets work just before Lawrence entered the building?

Tags: the-maze-runner

In *Maze Runner The Death Cure (2018)*, gun turrets didn't work when Lawrence just before entered the building.

[image]

Why didn't the gun turrets work just before Lawrence entered the building?

Answer (score 1):

> *Why didn't the gun turrets work just before Lawrence entered the building?*

This sequence of events starts at around 1:13:13 in the movie:

Gally gave the rebels total control of the defense systems when he drilled open a junction box on their return and plugged a wired device into it.

Back in the rebels stronghold, they report that they have a signal and are in, and the leader says "give me full control".

So, he has control of the guns and they now do not work when approached by the rebels.

> https://the-maze-runner-films.fandom.com/wiki/Lawrence
>
> Two nights later, when Thomas, Teresa, Newt, and Gally arrive in the WCKD tower to rescue Minho, **Gally plugs a jamming device into the electrical box**, allowing Lawrence's crew to **hack into WCKD's security systems** and **gun turrets** and **shut them down**.

[image]

> Thomas: Go, go, go.
>
> Gally: Hold on. Hold on.
>
> Gally: I can get in here.
>
> Gally: This'll work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> Rebel HQ, tech: We got a signal.
>
> Rebel HQ, 2IC: Gally did it.
>
> Rebel HQ, 2IC: We're in.

[image]

> Rebel HQ, Lawrence: Good.
>
> Rebel HQ, Lawrence: Give me everything.
>
> Rebel HQ, Lawrence: I want full control.

[image]

> WCKD security: That's funny. System's glitching.

https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=maze-runner-the-death-cure

Answer (score 0):

the device newt put on the electrical panel on the way downstairs to rescue Minho who isnt there

Comment: Could you [edit] this to expand on what you mean and provide evidence?

Comment: https://the-maze-runner-films.fandom.com/wiki/Lawrence - "Gally plugs a jamming device into the electrical box, allowing Lawrence's crew to hack into WCKD's security systems and gun turrets and shut them down."